# server giving msxml3.dll error '80072f7d' when trying to access secure url

Tags: ssl, asp-classic, msxml3

For years I have used classic asp to connect to the secure site of a supplier using msxml3.dll - but since this morning, I am getting;

```
msxml3.dll error '80072f7d' 

An error occurred in the secure channel support
```

I have had a good look around and can see that I am not the only one to have seen this - but cannot find a solution.

The partner site has just updated their ssl certificate. If I try to connect to the remote url from the server using IE or Chrome, it fails to connect reporting a nonvalid digital signature on the site's certificate. However, if I try to connect from my local computer, it works without a problem and I can see that the server identity has been correctly established.

Any help would be really appreciated.

Comment: Server is running Windows 2003

Comment: [Heartbleed](http://heartbleed.com/) has a lot to answer for. :)

Comment: This probably won't make any difference, but you could try modifying your code to use msxml6 - `Server.CreateObject("Msxml2.ServerXMLHTTP.6.0")`

Comment: @John - tried that but I get the same error - just with msxml6.dll instead.

Answer (score 4):

In Microsoft Windows Server 2003, applications that use the Cryptography API (CAPI) cannot validate an X.509 certificate. This problem occurs if the certificate is secured by the Secure Hash Algorithm 2 (SHA2) family of hashing algorithms. Applications may not work as expected if they require the SHA2 family of hashing algorithms.

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/938397 fixed the problem for me.