# msxml3.dll error '80090326' The message received was unexpected or badly formatted

Tags: vbscript, https, windows-xp

```
URL = "https://github.com/index.html"
Set xHttp = CreateObject("MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP")
xHttp.Open "GET", URL, False
xHttp.setOption 2, 13056
xHttp.Send()
```

can anybody tell, why this code works on windows7, and does not work on windows XP

**error**

```
msxml3.dll error '80090326' `
The message received was unexpected or badly formatted.`
```

on `xHttp.Send`

Answer (score 2):

I recently encountered a similar problem trying to retrieve a file via https onto a Windows 2003 server.  Turned out the problem was that the set of SSL/TLS ciphers supported on the client-side was so old that none of them was supported on the server.

In my case, the server was behind an AWS ELB, which was doing the https negotiation.  I was able to reconfigure the ELB to use an older cipher set (In the 'Listeners' tab, change the cipher config to use ELBSecurityPolicy-2015-05), and the client-side script magically started to work.

Answer (score 1):

We had to install the following KB in a Windows 2003 server:

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/948963

After this, another error:

msxml3.dll error '80072f7d'

An error occurred in the secure channel support

Thanks to this post ([server giving msxml3.dll error '80072f7d' when trying to access secure url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23216981/server-giving-msxml3-dll-error-80072f7d-when-trying-to-access-secure-url)) installed the http://support.microsoft.com/kb/938397 and worked.

When aplying to production, only the first KB solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you change the **MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP to MSXML2.XMLHTTP or Microsoft.XMLHTTP** it works or not for you ?

Try with this code and tell us if you get the same errors or not (tested only on windows 7)

```
On Error Resume Next
 Set File = WScript.CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
 File.Open "GET", "https://github.com/index.html", False
 'This is IE 8 headers
 File.setRequestHeader "User-Agent", "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 6.0; Trident/4.0; SLCC1; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; Media Center PC 5.0; .NET CLR 1.1.4322; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET CLR 3.0.30618; .NET4.0C; .NET4.0E; BCD2000; BCD2000)"
 File.Send
 If err.number <> 0 then 
    line =""
    Line  = Line &  vbcrlf & "" 
    Line  = Line &  vbcrlf & "Error getting file" 
    Line  = Line &  vbcrlf & "==================" 
    Line  = Line &  vbcrlf & "" 
    Line  = Line &  vbcrlf & "Error " & err.number & "(0x" & hex(err.number) & ") " & err.description 
    Line  = Line &  vbcrlf & "Source " & err.source 
    Line  = Line &  vbcrlf & "" 
    Line  = Line &  vbcrlf & "HTTP Error " & File.Status & " " & File.StatusText
    Line  = Line &  vbcrlf &  File.getAllResponseHeaders
    wscript.echo Line
    Err.clear
    wscript.quit
 End If

On Error Goto 0

 Set BS = CreateObject("ADODB.Stream")
 Set ws = CreateObject("wscript.Shell")
 BS.type = 1
 BS.open
 BS.Write File.ResponseBody
 BS.SaveToFile "Location.html", 2
 ws.run "Location.html"
```

Comment: yes, If i change the MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP to MSXML2.XMLHTTP  it works for me.

Comment: I use setoption, MSXML2.XMLHTTP write "Object doesn't  support this property or method"