# classic asp, MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP.6.0 web service call with certificate iussue

Tags: web-services, asp-classic, certificate

after days of failed attempts and research i need your help.

i'm trying tocall a web service to get a Token, the webservice it's protected by a certificate.

I have the .pem file with password and I converted it into .p12 using the mmc command to import it on IIS

If i call the https page by browser i can access easly, so the certificate it's ok.

If i try to connect with "curl" command on dos all work correctly

The problem is when i try to use the classic asp
I receive this error message:

**msxml6.dll error '80072f7d'

An error occurred in the secure channel support**

this is the code

```
Dim oRequest
Set oRequest = Server.CreateObject("MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP.6.0") 
oRequest.setOption(2) = 13056   
oRequest.setOption(3) = "LOCAL_MACHINE\My\" & CERIFICATE_NAME
oRequest.setTimeouts 10000, 10000, 10000, 10000 
msURL = WEBSERVICE_HTTPS_URL  
oRequest.Open "GET", msURL, False,USERNAME,PASSWORD   
oRequest.setRequestHeader "Authorization", "Basic " & Base64Encode("USERNAME:PASSWORD") 
oRequest.setRequestHeader "User-Agent", Request.ServerVariables("HTTP_User-Agent")
oRequest.setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "text/html;charset=ISO-8859-1"    
oRequest.send
```

any advice is appreciated,
Salvatore

Comment: What version of Windows?  Possibly this issue http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23216981/server-giving-msxml3-dll-error-80072f7d-when-trying-to-access-secure-url

Comment: i have Windows XP, 
with the hotfix i resolve!
thank you!